# What should I do when I run out of potions?

Tags: final-fantasy-16

I am a short way into the game, just reached Martha's Rest in Rosaria, and there is a large open map at this point. I have taken the opportunity to grind some AP.

However I only have a stock of 4 potions and 3 hi-potions. After a while these run out (I am playing Action Focused).

What can I do to replenish these?

Currently, I have to fast travel back to the Hideaway and purchase more potions from Charon. Meaning my grind essentially comes to a halt.

Alternatively, I can kill Clive, and re-spawn at the Obelisk with new potion stock, but this doesn't feel very efficient.

Comment: No need to go back to the Hideaway to buy more potions. Martha's Rest, for example, has a merchant (that does sell potions) left of the obelisk. Other open areas also tend to have at least one merchant.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There isn't really a way to replenish potions outside of buying them or getting them as a lucky pickup. But in the field those are very rare.

Your best bet instead is to mitigate the need for a potion use.

Torgal has cure, albeit it's fairly weak and as far as I know it can't heal pass your HP regain (faint parth of your healthbar after being damaged). But it can help keep you afloat for a little longer before needing to use a potion.

Unsure if you have it unlocked where you are in the game but Limit Break will regen your HP as well.

As a sidenote, there isn't really a need to grind AP in the long run.
You will get ways to get more AP along the way. Also, remember that you can freely regain spent AP from skills if you want to use them elsewhere.